# bootstrap up down vote button alignment on small screen

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to implement voting system like stack overflow, I'm having problem in displaying the arrows on small screens to be on the same line (arrows near the text) like stackoverflow.

On small screens it appears on 2 different lines as shown in this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ov0MO.jpg)

Here is what i did

```
<div class="row">

  <div class="col-md-2" style="font-size: 1em; color: #606060;">
     <span class="fa fa-caret-up"></span>
     <span>12</span>
     <span class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
   </div>                                                             
   <div class="col-md-10">
          <h3>Column</h3>    
           <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...</p>        
           <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...</p> 
    </div>
</div>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-1" style="font-size: 30px; color:#606060; text-align: center;">
        <span class="fa fa-caret-up col-md-12"></span>
        <span class="col-md-12">12</span>
        <!-- Number goes here -->
        <span class="fa fa-caret-down col-md-12"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-11">
        <h3>Column</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
        <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: In your HTML classes, you're saying that you want to have columns take up 1/6 and 5/6 on medium screens (the "md" part); try changing "md" to "xs"

Comment: please check the code snippet, it is shifted but still on 2 different lines

Comment: yes please @Amaresh S M

Comment: excellent, thats what i need @Amaresh S M thanks alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are u expecting like this:

```css
body{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
.row{
margin:0 !important;
}
.voting{
width:120px;
font-size: 2em;
color: #606060;
display:flex;
flex-direction:column; 
text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/ecdc7512a9.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="row">
  <div class="voting">
     <span class="fa fa-caret-up"></span>
     <span>12</span>
     <span class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
   </div>                                                             
   <div class="col-xl-8" style="width:calc(100% - 120px);">
          <h3>Column</h3>    
           <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...</p>        
           <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...</p> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

sorry, didn't get the problem at the first catch.. anyway.. this should help

```
<div class="row"  style="display:table;">
      <span class="fa fa-caret-up col-md-12" style=""></span>
      <span class="col-md-12" style="">12</span>
      <!-- Number goes here -->
      <span class="fa fa-caret-down col-md-12" style=""></span>
      <div class="col-xs-11"  style="table-cell">
        <h3>Column</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
        <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...</p>
        <h3>Column</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
        <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...</p>
        <h3>Column</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
        <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...</p>
      </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cpkgxd1y/1/

Comment: you should also concider giving your first cell a fixed width, e.g.
<div class="col-xs-1" style="width: 40px; ...

Comment: no problem, thanks for your help, it is also correct answer